# Searching within an associated array in ruby - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets say we have a Post model, a User model and a View model.

When a user views a post, a new record is created in the Views table. The table links the user, the post, and the current time. Later if that user goes back to view the post again, the record is updated with a new time. Pretty basic stuff.

Posts has_many views, and Users has_many views
Views belongs to Posts and Users

In the index view of the Posts, I want to call the specific view for each post i.e.

```
<% @Posts.each do |post| %>

<%= post.name %><br/>
<%= post.views %> # This connects all of the views related to this post.
                  # How do I get the only one connected to this post and the current_user.id? 

    <% end %>
```

I feel like theres some simple way of accomplishing this that I'm totally forgetting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
current_user.views.where(:post_id => post.id)
# this may work, not sure
current_user.views.where(:post => post)
```

or

```
post.views.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
# this may work, not sure
post.views.where(:user => current_user)
```

Comment: its funny - I had never thought about using the .where or .find_by route when not hitting the DB. I ended up going with: post.views.find_by_user_id(current_user.id) which worked like a charm. Thanks a ton Dogbert!

Comment: It is still hitting the database, rails is just smart enough to delay executing the query until it needs to... And won't be loading all of the views in this case, just the ones you are asking for. Take a look at the SQL generated by watching the logs.